# Error de SDK 25 en android

Tags: android-studio

Estoy tratando de iniciar mi proyecto en android studio, anteriormente me funcionaba bien, pero tuve que limpiar mi ordenador, volvi a instalar android y al inicarlo me aparecio el siguiente error:

> Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in:
>   C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk Possible cause: Build
>   properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25 Install missing platform(s) and sync
>   project

en realidad no se que quiera decir con ese error ya que jamas me habia aparecido

Comment: Asegurate de tener descargada la API 25 (Android 7.1.1 Nouget) desde Android SDK Manager

Comment: @MarcosMartínez ya lo revise y si la tengo instalada, ahorita la estoy desinstalando para volverla a isntalar en caso de que se haya instalado mal o algo por el estilo

Comment: No desinstales, sincroniza nuevamente tu proyecto o limpialo y vuelve a generarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Este error,

> Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in:
>   `C:\<ruta sdk>` Possible cause: Build properties not found for package
>   Android SDK Platform 25 Install missing platform(s) and sync project

es causado porque no esta instalado el SDK 25, y esta especificado seguramente ya sea en el `AndroidManifest.xml` o el archivo `build.gradle`.

Instala desde el SDK manager, revisa también los mensajes en la consola porque regularmente si se detecta este problema, se agrega un link para la instalación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No olvides sincronizar nuevamente el proyecto con los archivos gradle.

---

En cuanto al error:

> compile `Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:design:25.3.1`

tienes definida esta dependencia en tu build.gradle y necesitas instalarla.

Comment: lo he revisado y tengo esa api o sdk instalada. tambien me menciona errores de los compile `Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.3.1`

Comment: Cesar asegurate de tener instalado también el Support Repository en el cual tenes Android Support Repository y Google Repository.
Eso te debería resolver que no te encuentra las de support.design

Answer (score 0):

Usa estos valores:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Sería necesario que explicaras por qué esos valores solucionan el problema.